# Prevent string splitting in argument to readlink

Tags: bash, shell-script, symlink

I am writing a small script to symbolically link configuration files from my dotfiles directory to another one. I do not have control over the file names and unfortunately one of them is causing me a lot of trouble. The simplest reproducible case I have is as follows:

```
export file_name='My Configuration Text.theme'

readlink -f $file_name
```

Which predictably returns:

```
/home/me/folder/My
/home/me/folder/Configuration
/home/me/folder/Text.theme
```

I need this to not be split. I have also tried

```
readlink -f $(printf "%q " $file_name)
```

And it does not seem to fix the problem. Is there a solution to this or am I better off rewriting my linking script in something more robust like Python?

Comment: See the questions marked as duplicates. You need to double quote `$file_name` in the call to `readlink`.  There is no need to `export` the variable (at least not in relation to your issue or the resolution of it).

Comment: Got it, sorry for the dupe. Thank you!